# How we need work with snapshot and futurebuilder?

Tags: flutter

For the moment when i use futurebuilder and snapshot, i do like that : 
So in future i set the function with the data. After i test snapshot.connectionState with waiting. What do you think about this way of working, i am not sure it is correct

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: ListLotto,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return new Center(
                      child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return new Center(
                        child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),);
                    }
                    else {
                        List<Lotto_grid> values = snapshot.data;
                        if (values.isEmpty) {
                        return Container(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   FutureBuilder(
          future: myFuture,
          initialData: initialValue,//specify it if necessary
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            switch(snapshot.connectionState){
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if(snapshot.hasError) {
                  return myErrorWidget();
                } else if(snapshot.hasData) {
                  return MyDataWidget();
                } else{//if snapshot.data == null
                  return MyOtherWidget();
                }
              default:
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          }
      )
```

This one is better as it checks if data is null so you don't get `NullPointerException` at this line:

> List values = snapshot.data;